# How the Google App Engine's Blobstore Java API works?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, file-upload, blobstore

How the google app engine blobstore service working with file upload of 32 MB without any TimeOut Exception. Also it will not affect app engine's request-response interval of one minute.What kind of process is going behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the blobstore to upload data you upload the data into a special system handler that will load the data save it in the blobstore and when finished redirect to the user handler while providing a reference to to the location in the blobstore of the uploaded data.